# How to handle disagreements with supervisor on aspects of research?

Tags: computer-science, research-undergraduate

I am in a research project roughly related to applying machine learning in a particular application,
and the supervisors (multiple) has decided the main research direction, because my role is basically part of an undergrad research course.

However, I have some disagreements about aspects of the project. Firstly, they suggested using a particular dataset,
and after I read a paper about this dataset, I thought that it was not very related to the particular research question
that we were looking at. This is mainly because of the context the dataset was collected from,
and that the approach that the supervisors suggested appears to be unsuitable for this data.
If we drew conclusions from the analysis, then I feel that it will not
properly answer the question.

The supervisor disagreed with my doubt, but did not exactly explain why.

Also, their supervision is hands-off, and I wonder if there is some misunderstanding between us.

How should I handle these disagreements?

Comment: I feel that you need to talk more with your supervisor. We can give our general advice, but ultimately you and your supervisor decide on the next step. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disagreements are unavoidable when people work together on a project. The solutions to disagreements depend a lot on the balance of power and on the ego of the parties involved and a lot less on who has the best idea. If you want to get your way, you need to take that into account.

If you are a supervisor, you can just force your way. If you are not in charge, you need to discuss with your supervisor, until the correct solution becomes clear to them, too, assuming you know what is that solution.

Generally, it's a bad idea to frame things as your way vs their way. Even if you can force the other person to adopt your approach, you still didn't convince them. Even if you can prove with references and examples that your approach is a lot better, you still need to make them admit to themselves that your way is better then theirs. That's where ego comes into play. Sometimes, more senior people won't be able to accept a sound argument simply because it comes from someone they perceive as their juniors. It also goes the other way around. The one who has the sound solution won't budge and won't explain why because their colleague is "an idiot".

Not knowing your supervisor, it is unlikely I can give you a very useful advise on how to handle the disagreements with them. You need to talk to them a lot and present data. You might even need to try things their way and your way and show them the results. It might be sufficient to write everything in a short an clear email.

But, you should be mindful of the principles: be clear and concise, be respectful, don't start with the premise that you know better, and be open yourself to changing your mind in case your supervisor seems to have useful ideas.